# logarithmic exponential function python

Tags: python, matplotlib, mathematics

The code below (I found from googling) does the trick in terms of outcome. What I need to work out is the formula for this, so for any Y point we can get corresponding X.

This is part of a larger calculation using binned data Y to attribute time savings X.

Any help much appreciated.

[image: Jupyer Notebook]

[image: Plot]

Comment: please read the tour page [tour](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/tour) and the [What types of questions should I avoid asking](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) this is not really a question about data science. Also the question itself is not clear. "_I need to work out is the formula for this_ " are you looking for information about the logarithmic function?